# Polish tech tree, radio R-123

Tags: world-of-tanks

In the Polish tech tree, the medium tanks CS-59 and CS-63 both have a radio called R-123 with the same specs.
[image: Tech tree: CS-59]
[image: Tech tree: CS-63]

Why can't I use the radio R-123 from the CS-63 on the CS-59?

I cannot find any related information via Google. Also, I didn't hear anything about this in youtube videos about those two tanks that I watched so far.

**Update**

Meanwhile, I contacted the wargaming support.

My question:

> Warum ist das R-123 vom CS-63 nicht verwendbar mit dem CS-59, der auch ein
> R-123 Funkgerät im Forschungsbaum hat?

In English (translated by Google)

> Why is the R-123 from the CS-63 not usable with the CS-59, which also has an
> R-123 radio in the tech tree?

Their (stupid, sorry, it's stupid) answer:

> vielen Dank für die Rückmeldung.
>
> Vielen Dank für das Interesse an unserem Spiel. Leider können die Funkgeräte
> nicht von einem Tank zum anderen bewegt werden, selbst wenn beide Panzer
> dasselbe Funkgerät verwenden. Du musst sie zweimal recherchieren und kaufen.
> Ich hoffe, dass das die Situation klärt.
>
> Bei weiteren Fragen stehen wir gerne jederzeit zur Verfügung!
>
> Ich wünsche dir einen schönen Tag ,
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen,

In English:

> Thank you for the feedback.
>
> Thank you for your interest in our game. Unfortunately, the radios cannot be
> moved from one tank to another even if both tanks are using the same radio. You > have to research and buy them twice. I hope that clears up the situation.
>
> If you have any further questions, please do not hesitate to contact us!
>
> I wish you a nice day ,
>
> Best regards,

They don't really read your question and they don't understand their own game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I suggest to pop this question to Wargaming.net support!*

I have myself played WoT for 7 years, but stopped several years ago.
In the windows you can see the **Compatibility** (dependency) of the items, and I expect it to be a hardwired limitation via game database implementation. Having same name for the two items is truly confusing, and in general principles it is to be avoided. My "answer" is I believe it is an in-game bug, and the developers need to apply a fix for this.

Comment: I contacted the support. I added their "answer" to my question. I agree with you. I think it is a bug and they should fix it. But they don't listen and don't understand their own game. :/

Comment: The sad story is that they understood, and they stay on the worse choice. You can just swing the sword of justice and reply them: "To avoid confusion at least rename one radio (like tracks) to var.B!" Of course you may go on a longer battle if they will change the existing compability, but I expect them not willing to do.